# I am having difficulty mapping a PrimeFaces data table to my Managed Bean

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I think my problem is related to the fact that my Managed Bean constructor does not appear go get called.  That is if i put a breakpoint at the constructor the app does not stop at the breakpoint.

I get headers but not the row added in the constructor.

Here is my code:  First the xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <h:head>
            <f:facet name="first">
                <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
                <title>LOTTO CHECKER</title>
            </f:facet>
        </h:head>

        <h:body>

            <p:layout fullPage="true">

                <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="100" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                    LOTTO CHECKER
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                    Footer
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="175" header="Left" collapsible="true" >

                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                    <h:form id="powerBallDrawingForm">
                        <p:dataTable  value="#(lottoCheckerBean.powerBallDrawings}" var="powerBallDrawing"   >
                            <p:column headerText="DATE">

                                <h:outputText  value ="#{powerBallDrawing.drawingDate}"/>
                            </p:column >
                            <p:column headerText="BALL 1">

                                <h:outputText value="#{powerBallDrawing.ball_1}" />
                            </p:column>                 
                            <p:column headerText ="BALL 2"> 

                                <h:outputText value="#{powerBallDrawing.ball_2}" />
                            </p:column>    
                            <p:column headerText ="BALL 3">

                                <h:outputText value="#{powerBallDrawing.ball_3}" />
                            </p:column>    
                            <p:column headerText ="BALL 4">

                                <h:outputText value="#{powerBallDrawing.ball_4}" />
                            </p:column>    
                            <p:column headerText="BALL 5">

                                <h:outputText value="#{powerBallDrawing.ball_5}" />
                            </p:column>    
                            <p:column headerText="POWER BALL">

                                <h:outputText value="#{powerBallDrawing.powerBall}" />
                            </p:column>    
                        </p:dataTable>
                    </h:form>
                </p:layoutUnit>

            </p:layout>

        </h:body>

    </f:view>
</html>
```

Now the managed Bean

```
package PowerBall_BigBame_Checker;

import java.io.Serializable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;


@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped

public class LottoCheckerBean  implements Serializable {

    // Add business logic below. (Right-click in editor and choose
    // "Insert Code > Add Business Method")


    private List<PowerBallDrawing> powerBallDrawings; 

    public LottoCheckerBean()  {

       powerBallDrawings = new ArrayList<PowerBallDrawing>();
       powerBallDrawings.add( new PowerBallDrawing("03/16/2013",1,2,3,4,5,6));

    }







    public List<PowerBallDrawing> getPowerBallDrawings() {
        return this.powerBallDrawings;
    }

    public void setPowerBallDrawings(List<PowerBallDrawing> powerBallDrawings) {
        this.powerBallDrawings = powerBallDrawings;
    }


}
```

Finally the class that comprises a row of the table:

```
package PowerBall_BigBame_Checker;

import java.io.Serializable;


public class PowerBallDrawing implements Serializable {

    private String drawingDate;
    private int ball_1;
    private int ball_2;
    private int ball_3;
    private int ball_4;
    private int ball_5;
    private int powerBall;

    public PowerBallDrawing(String drawingDate, int ball_1, int ball_2, int ball_3,
            int ball_4, int ball_5, int powerBall) {

        this.ball_1 = ball_1;
        this.ball_2 = ball_2;
        this.ball_3 = ball_3;
        this.ball_4 = ball_4;
        this.ball_5 = ball_5;
        this.powerBall = powerBall;
        this.drawingDate = drawingDate;




    }

    public String getDrawingDate() {
        return drawingDate;
    }

    public void setDrawingDate(String drawingDate) {
        this.drawingDate = drawingDate;
    }

    public int getBall_1() {
        return ball_1;
    }

    public void setBall_1(int ball_1) {
        this.ball_1 = ball_1;
    }

    public int getBall_2() {
        return ball_2;
    }

    public void setBall_2(int ball_2) {
        this.ball_2 = ball_2;
    }

    public int getBall_3() {
        return ball_3;
    }

    public void setBall_3(int ball_3) {
        this.ball_3 = ball_3;
    }

    public int getBall_4() {
        return ball_4;
    }

    public void setBall_4(int ball_4) {
        this.ball_4 = ball_4;
    }

    public int getBall_5() {
        return ball_5;
    }

    public void setBall_5(int ball_5) {
        this.ball_5 = ball_5;
    }

    public int getPowerBall() {
        return powerBall;
    }

    public void setPowerBall(int powerBall) {
        this.powerBall = powerBall;
    }
}
```

I suspect I am violating a convention somewhere, but I am not seeing it.

Comment: Changing      <p:dataTable  value="#(lottoCheckerBean.powerBallDrawings}" var="powerBallDrawing"   >  to    <p:dataTable  value="#(lottoCheckerBean.powerBallDrawings}" var="PowerBallDrawing"   >  gets rid of the error, but I stil don't execute the constructor, so I get headings but no data.

Comment: You misspelled the value attribute: change `<p:dataTable  value="#(lottoCheckerBean.powerBallDrawings}" var="powerBallDrawing" >` to `<p:dataTable  value="#{lottoCheckerBean.powerBallDrawings}" var="powerBallDrawing" >`: inspect that EL expression must be enclosed inthe braces instead of the parentheses.

Comment: Your Managed bean should be tagged as .... @ManagedBean(name="lottoCheckerBean")

Comment: @rags: OP is just using the default value: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ManagedBeanNames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added your classes and jsf page to an existing project to see the error.

The only error you have is on this line

```
<p:dataTable  value="#(lottoCheckerBean.powerBallDrawings}" var="powerBallDrawing">
```

As stated in the comments you have a **(** in your EL expression. The correct definition is

```
<p:dataTable  value="#{lottoCheckerBean.powerBallDrawings}" var="powerBallDrawing">
```

No errors other than this.

Comment: Thank you for your time and your sharp eye.  I don't know how long I stared at that and didn't notice the paren where I wanted a curly brace.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written in the constructor should be inside the following method :

public void setPowerBallDrawings(List powerBallDrawings) {

}

This is because whenever you will try to access the variable then that corresponding setter method will be called .

Try this once. It should work .